# wfi to access point

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

I have samsung s3 unrooted running on jb v4.3.i want it to be used as such that i can access my wifi and my family also does it.hotspot does not solve my problem as it disables wifi and enables mobile network.i want to use wifi too.is there a way to solve this by app or something. thankyou in advance.

Comment: Clear me out: Why cannot your family members connect to the original Wi-Fi? Why do you have to be a medium?

Answer (score 1):

No. WiFi hotspot uses the WiFi radio, and so cannot be used for both tethering and WiFi reception at the same time. You would need 2 WiFi radios for that on your device, which I don't think any device has. You will be better off buying a router.